# Packaging up libcURL for easy distribution

Tags: c++, libcurl

So I want to package up a really simple and easy-to-use Twitter API that just accesses some of the basic public API calls (such as the public timeline).

To this end, I plan to wrap an API around libcURL to do this.

A couple of caveats.  First, I am designing this for students in a class I am TAing.  They are just learning how to program, so I need a cross-platform way to have it transparently and painlessly be included in their projects.

I've had difficulty with unresolved externals on Mac (I have almost no Mac C++ experience and am only OK at including packages on Windows).

How can I package libcURL this seamlessly?

I will select the answer that has lots of clarity and step-by-steps it, as I'm definitely a noob in this arena.

Comment: Okay, so I now have libcURL building on Mac, which is positive, though I'd still like a consistent and guaranteed way to package it up (preferably so it doesn't depend at all on what a student has installed on their system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather recommend that you install/require a libcurl installed from fink/macports that already do a good job at packaging libcurl.

Then you can instead focus your work to get your layer on top of that done really nice.

Comment: My concern with this approach is that this is behind-the-scenes code for an introductory-level course.  While many students will have no problem using a tool like fink, some might.  Also, this solution works on Mac, but installing libcurl on a PC is a bit tricker.

I could write/package up a python executable (separate mac/pc builds) and just read/write to a port or something, but that seems hideously inelegant.